# Form Always submitting with Javascript Confirm

Tags: javascript, php, sql

The form was working for a while but I moved some code around and can't revert (A lesson learned), now the code isn't working like it's supposed to.  In a nutshell, User clicks delete button > Delete button sends specific Entry ID to function, Function gets form ID, "Confirms delete", then should send to my delete_entry.php code.  Now, form is always submitting even when I hit "NO" and I added an alert to tell me which route it goes.

I've tried commenting out the form, and it still submits, so I don't think it's explicitly tied to the confirm function (Could be crazy though)

```
if ($entry['SubEntryID'] == "0") { ?>
<div id="post"><!-- This is the main post-->
    <div id="main">
        <div id="title">
            <?php echo $entry['EntryID']; ?>
            <?php echo $entry['Title']; ?>
        </div><br />
        <p><?php echo $entry['Body']; ?></p><br />
        <div id="postinfo">
          At: <?php echo $entry['CreateDate']; ?><br/>
          Posted by - <?php echo $entry['UserName']; ?>
        </div>
<!-- Start the form for the delete button -->
<form action="Delete_entry.php" method="post" id="Delete<?php echo $entry['EntryID'];?>">    
<input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="EntryID" value="<?php echo $entry['EntryID']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="UserID" value="<?php echo $entry['UserID']; ?>" />
<?php if ($userid == 1 || $userid == $entry['UserID']) { ?>
    <input onclick="confirmdelete('Delete<?php echo $entry['EntryID'];?>')" type="image" src="redx.png" alt="Delete Post" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Post"/>
<?php } ?><br />
        </form>
</div>
```

```
function confirmdelete(eid) {

    var retval = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?" + eid + "?");

    if (retval == true) {
        alert("You said Yes");
        document.getElementById(eid).submit();
        }
    else
    {
        alert("You said No");
    }
}
```

I want the delete button to call the function, the function to respond by submitting the form if it's true, and cancelling the form submission if false. The form page should only get called if confirm is true, and then submit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the confirmdelete() is not returning any true/false back so there is no code that stops the form from submission. Secondly, a form will submit anyway even if the function returns false because you have 2 submits (the form and the onclick).

Move the function call to onsubmit() of the form. Remove the onclick because the input type image submits the form by default. Here is the code:

Form:

```
<form action="Delete_entry.php" method="post" 
   id="Delete<?php echo $entry['EntryID'];?>" 
   onsubmit="return confirmdelete(<?php echo $entry['EntryID'];?>)">
```

Then the button (onclick removed):

```
<input type="image" src="redx.png" alt="Delete Post" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Post" />
```

Finally the JavaScript (returns true/false):

```
function confirmdelete(eid) {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?" + eid + "?")) {
        alert("You said Yes");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You said No");
        return false;
    }
}
```